# How to set grub2 to recognize xubuntu as xubuntu and not as ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop. And now I wanted to try Xubuntu and Lubuntu(both version 11.04). And when I installed Xubuntu and Lubuntu, grub2 recognize them both as Ubuntu instead of Xubuntu and Lubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The difference between Xubuntu and Lubuntu and Ubuntu is just in their set of packages. While for a user launching a system it is immediatelly clear whether is's ubuntu or xubuntu, it is quite difficult to guess that by inspecting the partirion's filesystem, which means GRUB may be unable to check that easily (though I do *not* say it's impossible).

Comment: ok, I understand, but, is there option somewhere in xubuntu/lubuntu to change the name from ubuntu to xubuntu/lubuntu, so grub will recognize it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. [Creating the Custom Menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Creating%20the%20Custom%20Menu)

You just follow these instructions and rename the partitions to X/Lubuntu.